# Adding widget to Header.php file doesn't show in the home page?

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

i am working on a simple WordPress blog and i am trying to display a widget that appears in every page in the website .. i have followed the dynamic sidebar widget approach, but the problem ,

here is the **Function.php** file

```js
function wpb_widgets_init() { 
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Custom Header Widget',
        'id'            => 'custom-header-widget',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="chw-widget">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="chw-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_widgets_init' );
```

and my **header.php** file

```html
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'custom-header-widget' ) ) : ?> 
                <div id="header-widget-area" class="chw-widget-area widget-area" role="complementary">
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-header-widget' ); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

and this works fine only in any **single post**.

but in the **home page/or any template file** nothing shows !!! 
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out 
i hade to create a template file for my new sideBar called: **sidebar-.php**
and use the **get_sidebar(id)** method to call it 
Voilet it works in all templates ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this structure and make sure your sidebar active

[image: this link click now]

Comment: Myside bar is active already and showing fine on the post details page, but it doesn't show up in any page template i have !